# Voltage issue on an esp32 wvroom 32D development board

Tags: esp32

I have an esp32 wroom 32 dev board. I'm running into power issues and I'm not sure what's going on.

When I try to upload sketches the uploads fail if I have any jumpers running to the 5v or 3.3v pins which is weird.

Also, when I have nothing plugged into the board other than the usb cable and try to measure voltage across the ground and power pins I get 1.5v from the 5v pin and 0 from the 3.3 pin

[image: 5v pin reading]

[image: 3.3 pin reading]

This is a brand new out-of-the-static-bag board and I'm having the same issue with another board of the same type.

I feel like there's something I'm missing. Any ideas?

Comment: Please verify your black wire is connected to GND and not to D3.

Comment: @VE7JRO yeah, the angle is odd in the picture, but the ground is definitely connected to the ground pin and not d3. I hooked it all back up just now to double check, still the same readings.

Comment: Is it possible to measure the voltage with the ESP32 un-plugged from the prototyping breadboard? One last suggestion, try a different volt meter if you have access to one.

Answer (score 1):

Try measuring the voltage against a different ground pin? I had a similar problem and discovered the pin next to the 5v input pin wasn't actually ground. Not sure why this would affect sketch uploading though..